# Single sign on in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, single-sign-on, mule-studio, josso

How to use Single-Sing-on (SSO) in Mule Community (or even Enterprise) Edition?
Is that possible, any connectors suports SSO (like JOSSO)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Anypoint's API management solution, you can use a SSO provider (such as ping federate) to protect your http endpoints. Is this what you were asking?